# How to use component from the old indy9 package

Tags: delphi, indy10, httpserver, indy-9

I have upgraded Indy9 to Indy10 in Delphi7. Took some time for me to change all the parts with TCP servers and clients but seems like it works nice now.

Now, i noticed one part is still not working, and thats idHTTPserver component.

Our applications web page is using a mootools library. With Indy9 idHTTPserver it works perfectly, however Indy10 does something, which makes browsers fail to display the page.

Besides some other errors, there is this nonsense error like (Firefox Error console output):

```
Timestamp: 2013.08.07 13:13:56
Error: SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
Source File: http://192.168.100.2:8780/lib/ui/core/mootools-1.2.4-more-yc.js
Line: 103, Column: 60
Source Code:
unction(){var b=["C?","C ","C","C?","C,","C¢","Cƒ","C£","C"","C¤","C.","C?","Ä,","Äƒ","Ä"","Ä.","Ä?","Ä?","ÄŒ","Ä¨","C?
-------------------------------------------------------------^
```

The actual source code inside this .js is:

```
long long text ....... function(){var b=["C?","C ","C","C?","C,","C¢","Cƒ","C£","C"","C¤","C.","C?","Ä,","Äƒ","Ä"","Ä.","Ä?","Ä?","ÄŒ","Ä¨","C?","C§","Ä?","Ä¸","Ä","Ä'","Cˆ","CØ","C?","C©","CŠ","CR","C<","C«","Äš","Ä>","Ä˜","ÄT","Ä?","ÄŸ","CŒ","C¬","C¨","C­","C?","C®","C¸","CÆ","Ä¹","Är","Ä½","Ä¾","Å","Å,","C'","C±","Å?","Åˆ","Åƒ","Å"","C'","C²","C"","C³","C"","C´","C.","Cµ","C-","C¶","C˜","Cø","Å'","Å˜","ÅT","Å"","Å.","Å ","Å?","Å?","ÅŸ","Åš","Å>","Å¤","Å?","Å¤","Å?","Å¢","Å£","CT","C¹","Cš","Cr","C>","C»","Cœ","C¼","Å®","ÅÆ","Åø","Cæ","C½","C¯","Å½","Å¾","Å¹","År","Å»","Å¼","C?","C¾","C","C°","CŸ","Å'","Å"","C?","C¦","Aµ"]; ................ long long text
```

What is happening here?

I took a deep breathe and thought, hey i could just use the old version of idHTTPserver as i still have the source files of Indy9 in the other folder.
If nobody knows how to fix the indy10 HTTPserver, could somebody please tell me how do i use the old version? Just the HTTPserver component (which surely links with 10s of other old indy files).

I tried to include the old sources, but it was becoming a mess, because it would use the idHTTPserver.pas from old version, yet idCustomHTTPserver.pas (this is what happens after i follow the uses of idHTTPserver.pas file) from new version...

Comment: The code Firefox complains about is wrong, but it matches what you say is in the file. You have a misplaced quotation mark. Maybe you need to escape it. This has nothing to do with Delphi or Indy. Your JavaScript is broken, and your browser noticed.

Comment: Are you sure it is a question mark at fault?  This look suspicious to me: `"C""`.  That is exactly where Firefox is pointing at. I would think the first `"` is terminating the string literal, and since there is no `,` or `]` after it, the array is malformed. So that first `"` would need to be escaped. Same thing with `"Ä""` and `"Å""`.

Answer (score 0):

To use a different Indy version in one project, set the project search path to Indy\Lib\Core, \Protocols and \System, and instantiate all components in code.

This also has the advantage that you can avoid the uninstall / install steps to switch between different Indy 10 versions.

Comment: That's not what the question asked. :-) It asked how to use the Indy9 IdHTTPServer only while still using the Indy10 versions of everything else.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not the direct answer to my own question in title, this did solve my problem.

I followed the function `HTTPserver.WriteContent` which led into `idHTTPServer.pas`, then compared idHTTPServer.pas files of Indy9 and Indy10, the parts about encoding in Indy10 caught my attention.

At line 2039 i have removed the second argument of the write function

`FConnection.IOHandler.Write(ContentText, CharsetToEncoding(CharSet));`
replaced with
  `FConnection.IOHandler.Write(ContentText);`

This solved my problem. Everything works fine now.

The main problem here was, as commenters have noticed, the extra " symbols. 
I was quite stupid because i clicked the link in the firefox console and it opened the javascript file which was of wrong version and for some reason i thought this was what it was supposed to be. Only a bit later i decided to check the actual file on my PC and it turned out that `"C""` was not even C, the actual text is this

```
var b=["À","à","Á","á","Â","â","Ã","ã","Ä","ä","Å","å","Ă","ă","Ą","ą","Ć","ć","Č","č","Ç","ç","Ď","ď","Đ","đ","È","è","É","é","Ê","ê","Ë","ë","Ě","ě","Ę","ę","Ğ","ğ","Ì","ì","Í","í","Î","î","Ï","ï","Ĺ","ĺ","Ľ","ľ","Ł","ł","Ñ","ñ","Ň","ň","Ń","ń","Ò","ò","Ó","ó","Ô","ô","Õ","õ","Ö","ö","Ø","ø","ő","Ř","ř","Ŕ","ŕ","Š","š","Ş","ş","Ś","ś","Ť","ť","Ť","ť","Ţ","ţ","Ù","ù","Ú","ú","Û","û","Ü","ü","Ů","ů","Ÿ","ÿ","ý","Ý","Ž","ž","Ź","ź","Ż","ż","Þ","þ","Ð","ð","ß","Œ","œ","Æ","æ","µ"];
```

So, i was right. When the whole text goes through CharsetToEncoding, it translates all these single symbol characters into 2 symbols.

I will not accept my own answer as it doesnt really answer the title question and i would love to know if its possible to use a single component of older version while the rest are newer.